# Angular facnybox not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fancybox

I am trying to implement fancy box functionality. I've created a plunker and it works on plunker
      [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SJrWWoKSa4kGFP7qywlQ?p=preview) but in my host I got

```
 Error: $.fancybox is not a function .link/<@file:///C:/Users/h166622/Desktop/Angular/js/core/directives.js:99:6
```

How it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are linking your stylesheets and some javascript with only `"//domain.com/xxxxx"`. Doing it this way is great for production sites, or even sites configured locally with the use of virtual hosts. If you were to copy/paste the code and just open the `.html` file in your browser, it loads that file locally, thus links that do not specify a header (i.e. `http` or `https`) will try to find those links locally as well.

- *http:* //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css
- *http:* //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js

The use of *//* insted of *http://* is what is known as **protocol-relative** URLs. This way, if a browser is viewing a page through an *HTTPS** protocol, the asset will also be loaded using an **HTTPS** protocol. Same applies to general **HTTP** protocols.

So unless you configure a virtual host to do local site development, I would change those links. Another thing to note, is that your application is linked to `app.js` linking to a local file when viewing a `.html` file is usually fine so long as both exist within the same directory. Otherwise, you'll need to include and edit your application javascript through the use of inline `<script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>` tag.